# Add firewall rules over PowerShell from data in Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to create new firewall rules from a long list from excel file. I'm going to use PowerShell and ImportExcel module for that purpose. Considering I'm noobie in Windows and PowerShell I need help in how to actually do this.

First column from excel represent IpAndPorts, I need to block and add as firewall rule.
I need to get data from "Row 2" and until end of excel data.

**Here is the example of excel:**

| Excel-Row | IpAndPorts | Protocol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 35.180.0.0/16 | TCP |
| 3 | 12.13.14.1/8883,433 | TCP |
| 4 | 1.2.3.4/80 | HTTP |

I also need to make -DisplayName & -Name in New-NetFirewallRule command to be dynamic, so I can later on find the firewall rule (some code example).

**The command in PowerShell I will use for creating firewall rule:**

New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block WiFi **{Excel-Row}**" -Name "Block Wifi **{Excel-Row}**" -Direction Inbound -InterfaceType Wireless -Action Block -RemoteAddress **{Part before / IpAndPorts}** -LocalPort **{Part after / IpAndPorts}** -Protocol **{Protocol}**

**Example of command after getting data from Row 3 from Excel:**

New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block WiFi **3**" -Name "Block Wifi **3**" -Direction Inbound -InterfaceType Wireless -Action Block -RemoteAddress **12.13.14.1** -LocalPort **8883,433** -Protocol **TCP**

UPDATE:
**Here is the code what I manage to write:**

```
# ---------------------------------------
# Here we should get data from excel
# and prepare variables

$FirewallList = Import-Excel C:\Temp\list.xlsx
$All = $FirewallList.IpAndPorts
$AllProtocols = $FirewallList.Protocol

# ---------------------------------------
# Here it should be number of excel row, 
# starting from 2 and incementing until last data in row
# Don't know how to do that

$Index = "1"

# ---------------------------------------
# Split IpAndPorts data to get IP and PORT

$Ip = $All.Split("/")[0]
$Port = $All.Split("/")[1]

# ---------------------------------------
# Here we should populate parameters

#$Params = @{ 
#    "DisplayName" = 'Block-WiFi-' + $Index  
#    "Name" = 'Block-WiFi-' + $Index 
#    "Direction" = 'Inbound' 
#    "InterfaceType" = 'Wireless'
#    "Action" = 'Block'
#    "RemoteAddress" = $Ip
#    "LocalPort" = $Port
#    "Protocol" = $AllProtocols
#}

# Here we should start the command
# New-NetFirewallRule @Params

# ---------------------------------------
# Test how the command will be assembled 
# based on data from excel

$Test = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    DisplayName = "Block-WiFi-" + $Index  
    Name = "Block-WiFi-" + $Index 
    Direction = 'Inbound' 
    InterfaceType = 'Wireless'
    Action = 'Block'
    RemoteAddress = $Ip
    LocalPort = $Port
    Protocol = $AllProtocols
}

Write-Host "New-NetFirewallRule
-DisplayName $($Test.DisplayName)
-Name $($Test.Name)
-Direction $($Test.Direction) 
-InterfaceType $($Test.InterfaceType)
-Action $($Test.Action)
-RemoteAddress $($Test.RemoteAddress)
-LocalPort $($Test.LocalPort)
-Protocol $($Test.Protocol)
"
# Test results. Just printing
Write-Host "------------- PRINT FROM EXCEL ----------------"
$All
$AllProtocols
Write-Host "---------------------------------------------"
$Ip
$Port
```

**How to make loop to take each value from excel, add in to $Params and lunch the command?**

Thanks in advance..!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you load your Excel file

```
$FirewallList = Import-Excel C:\Temp\list.xlsx
$All = $FirewallList.IpAndPorts
$AllProtocols = $FirewallList.Protocol
```

Try doing `$FirewallList.Count` - that's the number of rows.

Then you can access each row by changing `i` in `$FirewallList[i]` (starts from 0), same for other variables above.

For your example:

```
$FirewallList.Count
3


$FirewallList[0]
IpAndPorts          Protocol
----------          --------
35.180.0.0/16       TCP
```

You can also use foreach loop to go through all the elements.